# Why can i invoke a variable in JavaScript as a function due to the Function Expression variety?

Tags: javascript, function-expression

```js
const result =  (numberOne, numberTwo) => 
{
  if(numberOne > numberTwo){
    return true;
  } else {
    return false;
  }
};

console.log(result(1, 2)); // here i use the variable as a function?!
```

So why can i use a variable as a function?

Comment: Functions are first class citizens. The variable IS the function.

Comment: Thank you very much, now i see. I appreciate your answer.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [var functionName = function() {} vs function functionName() {}](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/336859/var-functionname-function-vs-function-functionname)